# Vue 3.0 VsBreadcrumb error - Prop being mutated: "items"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuex

I am developing a website using vuesax theme.
vue cli 3.0

**Default Layout Page**

```
<template>
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <!---Navigation-->
        <Navbar
          :topbarColor="topbarColor"
          :logo="require('@/assets/images/logo/logo-light-icon.png')"
          :title="logotitle"
        />
        <!---Sidebar-->
        <SideBar parent=".main-wrapper" />
    
        <Breadcrumbs :pageTitle="pageTitle" :breadcrumbLinks=breadcrumbLinks />
          
        <!---Page Container-->
        <div class="main-container-fluid">      
          <slot />
        </div>
      </div>
    </template>
```

**Dashboard Component**

```
<template>
  <DefaultLayout :pageTitle="$t('dashboard.pageTitle')" :breadcrumbLinks=breadcrumbLinks>
  <div>
    <States />
    <vs-row vs-justify="center">
      <vs-col vs-lg="12">
        <vs-card>
          <div slot="header">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <div>
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $t('dashboard.projects.recent') }}</h5>                
              </div>
              <div class="ml-auto text-right">
                <div>
                  <span class="text-muted">{{ $t('dashboard.projects.total') }}</span>
                  <h2 class="text-success mb-0">90</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <RecentProjects />
        </vs-card>
      </vs-col>
    </vs-row>
  </div>
  </DefaultLayout>
</template>
<script>
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/DefaultLayout";
import RecentProjects from "../components/dashboard/RecentProjects.vue";
import States from "../components/dashboard/States.vue";
export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  components: {    
    RecentProjects,
    States,      
    DefaultLayout
  },
  data: () => ({    
    breadcrumbLinks: [
      {
        title: global.vm.$t('breadcrumbs.home'),
        url: ""
      },
      {
        title: global.vm.$t('breadcrumbs.dashboard'),
        active: true
      }
    ],
  })
};
</script>
```

**Breadcrumbs Component**

```
<template>
  <vs-row class="vs-breadcrumb-row" vs-type="flex" vs-justify="space-around">
      <vs-col
          type="flex"
          vs-justify="center"
          vs-align="center"
          vs-lg="12"
          vs-sm="12"
          vs-xs="12"
          code-toggler
        >
        <vs-card class="br-0">
          <h4 class="card-title mb-0 d-flex">
            <vs-row vs-justify="space-between" vs-align="center">              
            {{ pageTitle }}                        
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <vs-breadcrumb separator="chevron_right"  
                :items="breadcrumbLinks"
                ></vs-breadcrumb>              
            </div>  
            </vs-row>            
          </h4>                      
        </vs-card> 
        </vs-col> 
  </vs-row>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "Breadcrumbs", 
  props: {
    pageTitle: {
      type: String
    },
    breadcrumbLinks: {
      type: Array
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

I am getting the following error
[image]

and also I have integrated vue i18n module, translation is working fine except for one condition: when I change from EN to FR the current page breadcrumbs translation doesn't change, it still remains in EN, but it's changed to FR when I switch to other pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i18n translates should be a computed property, this is the reason you are getting warnings.

The `breadcrumbLinks` prop is mutating on the child component whenever you switch one language from another, and this is the reason that breadcrumb translations aren't working, just use a computed property instead:

```js
<template>
  <DefaultLayout :pageTitle="$t('dashboard.pageTitle')" :breadcrumbLinks=breadcrumbLinks>
  <div>
    <States />
    <vs-row vs-justify="center">
      <vs-col vs-lg="12">
        <vs-card>
          <div slot="header">
            <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
              <div>
                <h5 class="card-title">{{ $t('dashboard.projects.recent') }}</h5>                
              </div>
              <div class="ml-auto text-right">
                <div>
                  <span class="text-muted">{{ $t('dashboard.projects.total') }}</span>
                  <h2 class="text-success mb-0">90</h2>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <RecentProjects />
        </vs-card>
      </vs-col>
    </vs-row>
  </div>
  </DefaultLayout>
</template>
<script>
import DefaultLayout from "../layouts/DefaultLayout";
import RecentProjects from "../components/dashboard/RecentProjects.vue";
import States from "../components/dashboard/States.vue";
export default {
  name: "Dashboard",
  components: {    
    RecentProjects,
    States,      
    DefaultLayout
  },
  computed: {    
    breadcrumbLinks() {
      return [
        {
          title: global.vm.$t('breadcrumbs.home'),
          url: ""
        },
        {
          title: global.vm.$t('breadcrumbs.dashboard'),
          active: true
        }
      ],
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. now the breadcrumb translation works but still I am getting vue warning. _Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "items"_

Comment: the error / warn occurs in **Breadcrumbs Component** please check that code. thank you